# Android Fragment only uses last value for edittext after second "refresh"

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

I've got a fragment which dynamially adds LinearLayouts with two imagebuttons and a edittext.
The Value from the edittext is stored in a .txt File and retrieved via the function retrievecounter.

This is the Layout which gets added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_photo" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/singelfirstet1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="85"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/button_delete_row_description"
        android:src="@drawable/testi" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    ScrollView mLinearLayout = (ScrollView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.editlistsfirst, container, false);


     operations = new ArrayList<String>();

     operations = retrievecounter(0);


    temp = (LinearLayout) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.lineartest);
    LayoutInflater inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    for (int i = 0; i < operations.size(); i++) {

        View tempr = (inflater2.inflate(R.layout.list_singlefirst,
                container, false));

        ImageButton bt = (ImageButton) tempr
                .findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);

        EditText et = (EditText) tempr.findViewById(R.id.singelfirstet1);

        et.setText(operations.get(i));

        String show = et.getText().toString();
        Log.w("Class",show);

        bt.setOnClickListener(this);
        temp.addView(tempr);


    }



    return mLinearLayout;
}
```

I navigate between the fragments via an actionbar with tabs.

This is my onTabselected function:

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
}
```

On the first click the values from the .txt file are displayed correctly, but after i switch to a different tab/fragment and back to this fragment only the last value of my ArrayList gets displayed.

Strange however is that the Log.w displays the correct value for the edittext both times.

Any idea what causes this?

Thanks in advance

If i call my function of the button inside the linearlayout:

```
temp.removeView((View) v.getParent());
```

for all buttons till all layouts are gone and go to another tab and back it displays the correct values, but i've got no idea why. Maybe this is helpful in finding the problem.

edit2: I Found a solution, don't know if it is practical or why it works but it does:

```
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    temp.removeAllViews();
}
```

After i added this it works. If someone could explain why that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things to consider when dealing with Views like this is that they are only 'updated' when they are first created. When you switch between your tabs, the data will not be refreshed because it was A)Not recreated [refreshed] B)Not updated by an adapter.

When you removed all views on `Pause()`, you emptied your view, then it is recreated from your `replace()` function which is similar as creating a new view. Refreshing a layout by removing and re-adding everything every time you change something can become very computationally expensive which is why people will use an adapter to control their layouts.

Comment: But why does the data change when it isn't refreshed?

Comment: The data is changed as the values you use are being reassigned, the display is not since it will only 'refresh' if you recreated it.